# Chrome extension to popup when you get notifications from StackExchage, Quora or other similar websites?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, notifications

I am looking for a single Chrome extension that can be used to notify you when someone replies to one of your questions on Q&A site like one form SE, Quora or similar.

I do not use email notifications due to spam :)

Answer (score 3):

It can here https://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing

For Chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bpficcollblmkmoofnbnfhibdhfolamm

FireFox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-alert/

Opera
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackalert/stackalert.oex

I guess nothing for IE?

And it's quite slow in FireFox (as in very slow!)